# Highcharts - attach event on crosshair click

Tags: highcharts

I need to attach a click event to the column chart crosshair, and have found the black label "customEvents.js" module:

https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events

As a beginner I just can't seem to figure out how to get this working. I would be grateful if someone could modify the demo fiddle to show me how it's done! I've tried placing the "crosshair" tag inside "plotOptions", inside "xAxis", and on its own, but without success.

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Utx8g/

```
crosshair: {
    enabled: true,
    events: {
                        dblclick: function () {
                            $('#report').html('dbclick on xAxis label');
                        },
                        click: function () {
                            $('#report').html('click on xAxis label');
                        },
                        contextmenu: function () {
                            $('#report').html('context menu on xAxis label');
                        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like a regression, so I reported it on the plugin github: https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events/issues/133

As a workaround, you can add `pointerEvents: 'auto'` style.

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'drawCrosshair', function(proceed) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        if (this.cross) {
            this.cross.css({
                pointerEvents: 'auto'
            });
        }
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pfkmg39x/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts